# How to stop SQL server restore from overwriting database?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I have a ELMAH database that I want to script the restore of using the following:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [Elmah] 
FROM DISK = N'E:\Elmah_backup_2012_11_02_030003_1700702.bak' 
WITH FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'Elmah' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Elmah.mdf',  
MOVE N'Elmah_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Elmah.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
GO
```

Even though I am not including `WITH REPLACE` each time I execute this statement it restores over the existing database.

I will always drop all databases before this operation and I never want this code to accidentally restore a database over one in production.

How do I change this code so that it will never overwrite an existing database?

I am actually doing this through SMO objects but the principle and results are the same so I am hoping to keep this simplified to just the TSQL necessary in the hopes that I can generalize that information to what needs to be set on the appropriate SMO.Restore object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to (a) give the restored database a new logical name, and (b) you need to define new physical file names, so the existing ones won't be overwritten. Try something like this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [Elmah_Restored]       <== new (and unique) logical database name
FROM DISK = N'E:\Elmah_backup_2012_11_02_030003_1700702.bak' 
WITH FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'Elmah' TO 
     N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Elmah_restored.mdf',   <== new (and unique) physical file name
MOVE N'Elmah_log' TO 
     N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Elmah_restored_log.ldf',   <== new (and unique) physical file name
NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
GO
```

Comment: Marc_S, thank you for that information. What I am trying to accomplish is not restoring the backup under a different name, what I want is the backup process to fail instead of automatically overwriting the database. Essentially I want the if exists then fail semantics but I want the restore job itself to fail without me checking whether the database exists. Is there a no overwrite option?

Comment: @ObligatoryMoniker: the T-SQL `RESTORE` statement I have shown in my answer will **NOT** overwrite an existing database. For that to happen, you would need to add a `REPLACE` clause (e.g. after the `NOUNLOAD`)